# Do supervised methods outperform unsupervised methods for generic multi-document summarization of news?

Tags: natural-language, text-summarization

{1} says:

> For generic multi-document summarization of news, supervised methods have not been shown to outperform competitive unsupervised methods based on a single feature such as the presence of topic words and graph methods.

The paper was written five years ago. Are supervised methods still unable to outperform unsupervised methods for generic multi-document summarization of news?

---

References:

- {1} Nenkova, Ani, and Kathleen McKeown. "A survey of text summarization techniques." Mining text data (2012): 43-76. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8d7f/6dc8b0b9101580cc96f1f303d1eba3d590af.pdf ; https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=6478246476126759903&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5